# I want to display Google Adsense on my gatsby.js site. However, it is not showing up

Tags: reactjs

I want to display Google Adsense on my gatsby.js site. However, it is not showing up.
LeftSideSection is called in Layout.js.

I am running it in a local environment.
And I don't have a domain for my site.

I don't register my site's domain in GoogleAdsense and
I have created an Ad unit.

export
[[image]
googleAdsense.js

```
 import React from "react"
 import * as styles from "./LeftSideSection.module.css";
 import {Adsense} from './googleAdsense'
 import React, { useEffect } from 'react'


export const Adsense = ({ path }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    ;(window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({})
  }, [path])

  
  return (
      
    <ins 
      className="adsbygoogle"
      style={{ "display": "block" , textAlign: "center",width:`100%` ,height:`100%`}}
      data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxx"
      data-ad-slot="xxxxxxx"
      data-ad-format="auto"
      data-full-width-responsive="true"
      data-adtest="on"
           />
  )
  }
```

LeftSideSection.js

```
const LeftSideSection = (props) => {
  const { title, children } = props;
  const path = props.location?.pathname || '';

  return (
    <section className={styles.container}>
      <p>ads</p>
         <Adsense path={path} />

    </section>
  );
};

export default LeftSideSection;
```

Layout.js

```
  import React from "react";
    import Header from "./Header";
    import * as styles from "./Layout.module.css";
    import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    import herderImage from '../images/header.png'
    import {Navbar} from 'react-bootstrap'
    import RightSideSection from "./RightSideSection";
    import LeftSideSection from "./LeftSideSection";
    import { Link } from "gatsby";
    import { useBreakpoint } from 'gatsby-plugin-breakpoints';
    import HeaderRss from "./HeaderRss";
    
    const Layout = ({ children }) => {
      const breakPoints = useBreakpoint();
      return (
        breakPoints.pc ?
        <>
        <Navbar.Brand as={Link} href='/' >
          <img src={herderImage} style={{width:`100%`,height:`200px`,}}/>
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Header />
      
          <div className={styles.container}>
           
    
            <div className={styles.LeftSideSection}>
    <LeftSideSection  />
    </div>
    <div className={styles.RightSideSection}>
    <RightSideSection />
    </div>
    
    <div className={styles.mainPane}>
    <div className={styles.headerRssContainer}>
            <HeaderRss/>
            </div>
    {children}
    </div>
          </div>
    
          <footer className={styles.footer}>
            © {new Date().getFullYear()}, 
            {`title`}
          </footer>
    
        </>:
   );
    }; 
    
    
    export default Layout;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amT1C.jpg)

Comment: What's `ins` and what's inside `import {Adsense} from './googleAdsense'`? If you haven't registered your domain on Adsense console, how did you get the `data-ad-client`? Is it from test?

Comment: thanks!I I have added the images.
It would be helpful if you could take a look.

Comment: sorry, I was wrong.
I had left adblock in and was running it.
When I removed the adblock, the GoogleAdsense link showed up.
However, the image of the ad did not show up.

Comment: I repaierd it. sorry

Answer (score 0):

You are not loading the `<script>` that the console is suggesting. Try using the `Helmet` component to do something like:

```
 import React from "react"
 import * as styles from "./LeftSideSection.module.css";
 import {Adsense} from './googleAdsense'
 import React, { useEffect } from 'react'


export const Adsense = ({ path }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    ;(window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({})
  }, [path])

  
  return <>
          <Helmet>
           <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
         </Helmet>
         <ins 
          className="adsbygoogle"
          style={{ "display": "block" , textAlign: "center",width:`100%` ,height:`100%`}}
          data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxx"
          data-ad-slot="xxxxxxx"
          data-ad-format="auto"
          data-adtest="on"
          data-full-width-responsive="true"
        />
      </>
     }
```

I still don't know what's `import {Adsense} from './googleAdsense'`, this line may collide with the naming of the component that you are defining (both are `Adsense`). If the issue persists, try changing the name.

To make the ads available on localhost, set the `data-adtest` as `on`.

In addition, you can try using a React-based solution like the one that [`react-adsense`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-adsense) suggests.

Double-check and remove AdBlocks (or similar).

> However, the image of the ad did not show up.
> This can be caused by the `localhost`. Try deploying the site to check it in a real domain.

Comment: I tried. But it didn't work.

Comment: I've added Layout.js. I hope you can see it.

Comment: You are still not sharing `import {Adsense} from './googleAdsense'` this. The `Layout` doesn't add relevant information here. When you said "I tried. But it didn't work" what do you mean? Have you tried the `react-adsense`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot.
I changed it to {GoogleAdsense}.
But it doesn't work.

I entered <script>---</script> in the Helmet tag.
But it did not work.

Comment: But what's the output? What's the console showing up? What's going on? Please edit what have you tried

Comment: I have uploaded the screenshot of the output.

Comment: If you change everything to GoogleAdsense the issue is the same... You are defining a component that is being imported in the same place... And I wanted to see the output of the console... not the DOM. Have you tried `react-adsense`? In addition, to make the ads available on localhost, have you set the `data-adtest="on"` as the answer suggests?

Comment: I typed in data-adtest and it did not show up.
I have posted the text that shows up on rebuild.

Comment: Have you tried `react-adsense`?

Comment: I challenged react-adsense.
However, I got an error.I've uploaded the code and images.
I hope you can check it.

Comment: Try to share a Codesandbox. It's messy with all the snippets unordered with your current configuration. As I've been saying, you have a messy configuration naming between you create and what you export, and it's what is breaking the code right now. You are missing a `export GoogleAdsense`

Comment: thanks,I made it https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-wu-861n7?file=/src/components/Layout.js

Comment: If you export something as `default`, needs to be imported `import GoogleAdsense  from "./googleAdsense"`...

Comment: I'm importing it in LeftSideSection.js.

By the way, when I press the F12 key on <GoogleAdsense />.
It doesn't transition to GoogleAdsense.js.

Comment: I saw where you import it... Please pay attention to what I suggest. Import it like this: `import GoogleAdsense  from "./googleAdsense"` (**without** brackets`{}`). The components you export by default **needs** to be imported **without** curly braces)

Comment: thanks,import GoogleAdsense from". /GoogleAdsense 
You are right, when I remove {}, the error that was displayed in the browser disappeared.

However, Adsense is not displayed.

Comment: The sandbox's purpose is to help to debug but it becomes completely useless if you don't share logs, debugging, or the configuration you have in your project. If you don't know why the "adsense is not displayed" imagine us while reading the answer without debugging details... Star checking if the `adsbygoogle.js` is being loaded

Comment: Deploy the site and test it in a real domain.